# How do I downgrade a package in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, package

The new version of the package `u2622-persistent-session` crashes my entire app with no hope to troubleshoot it, so naturally I wanted to downgrade it to 0.3.5 again but found it impossible.

I rolled back everything in git to the version where everything was working, no luck.

I deleted the package manually and did `meteor add u2622:persistent-session@0.3.5`, no luck.

I changed the value that says `0.4.4` in the file `packages` but it changes back immediately again.

What the heck do I do to downgrade a package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/i/installing) from `atmospherejs` ? It should be

`meteor add u2622:persistent-session@=0.3.5`

(`=` after `@`)